# Is the Flores Consent Decree binding nationally and currently?

Tags: united-states, law

In reading the Flores Consent Decree, I see it called for the decree to be terminated after 5 years (or earlier if all parties agreed). So why is it still in force? Also, my understanding is that consent decrees are only binding in the jurisdiction of the court that issued it. So why would this decree be binding nationally?

Comment: should this Q be migrated to  Law S.E.

Comment: [Full text of the Flores consent decree](https://www.conservativedailynews.com/2018/06/flores-consent-decree-of-1997-full-text/).  Not the most readable copy, but online.

Comment: The agreement was subsequently extended.